# Ran wrong script, moved folders are gone, but where?

Tags: bash, shell-script, mv

I accidentally ran wrong bash script, while trying to move files. All the folders starting like "Lisa" gone and not moved. Below are the rough content of the wrong script.

```
folder_path = "/media/hdd/folder/"
Lisa = "/media/hdd/folder/folder1/Lisa/"

mv $folder_path Lisa* $Lisa
```

All the folders starts with Lisa are gone, I checked `/media/hdd/folder/folder1/Lisa/` but they are not there. I assume they are deleted but `df -h` still reports the same free space before I ran the wrong script.

I couldn't find anything using `lsof`.
Are the folders deleted or something else?
Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Post the *exact* commands run, not an approximation.

Comment: Have you tried running `find`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with your syntax that would cause some problems. In bash (though I'm not sure if that's how you ran this script), the `=` operator does not perform assignment if there are spaces around it. That is, `x=y` assigns `y` to `x`, but `x = y` compares `x` and `y`. Since you have spaces, I'll assume that both `folder_path` and `Lisa` are unset (since no assignment was performed).

If that's the case, on the `mv` line, `$folder_path` and `$Lisa` expanded to an empty string. So, you basically ran this:

```
mv Lisa*
```

This expands to everything starting with "Lisa" in your current working directory. Depending on what you have in there, this could do a few different things, including overwriting, moving, and renaming these files.

Comment: I know, thank you for your explanation. This was supposed to be python script but I accidentally ran as bash script. I want to know, if folders are gone or copied somewhere else, I couldn't figure it out because I have the same exact disk space before I ran the script and /media/hdd/folder/folder1/Lisa/ folder is empty.

Comment: In the future, put a `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your script to make sure your shell will run it as such. As for finding the files, we can't really help you. You could run `find . -name "*Lisa*"` to find any files/directories containing the string "Lisa" recursively in your current directory.

Comment: OK I found them. Let me explain, if I can... find . -iname Lisa* returns nothing. Command ls -larth shows nothing about Lisa, so as ls, but if I type cd Lisa. and hit Tab key cd enters Lisa.z..... folder and everything is there. I don't know why ls and ls -larth doesn't show this Lisa.z... folder I am really curious.

Comment: Both `find` and `ls` are able to find a folder named "Lisa.z" on my machine without special options. I'm not sure what's wrong with your setup.